# Nogotofail usage android pentesting

Tags: tls, android, proxy, tools

I was looking at the google tool: Nogotofail https://github.com/google/nogotofail

I used their examples to set it up and this works for the examples with proxychains.

But now I want to use it with my android device or android emulator (SDK or Genymotion). But this is where I just do not understand what I have to do.

I tried:
- Installing their "App" but this just crashes on my device or gives 2 options "SSL/TLS" and "HTTP" in an emulator and doesn't do anything
- Just proxying all traffic to my machine on 8443, this gives a lot of bad handshake errors in nogotofail
- Proxying through Burp to nogotofail, which gives the same bad handshake errors.

From google's documentation I understand that it should work on a router or VPN. But I don't understand how to get that to work via my normal computer, and why it would not work by just proxying (like Burp works).

I think I am missing some base level understanding of this problem, but the documentation doesn't help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you have provided, the issue is most likely due to a routing problem. You forgot to mention whether you tried it with Genymotion? If you did, the VM is in NAT config and may not be connecting properly.  Have you installed all three components required for MITM to work? To set it up with google cloud instance, did you try [this](https://github.com/google/nogotofail/blob/dev/docs/gce/readme.md) documentation?

Comment: I will try from that link (I didn't find that link as I didn't know what that was :D). Is there anyway to not make this large setup (GCE I consider large) and just do it on a local laptop? And is there maybe a more basic tutorial on how to set up an environment like that on a local machine? (I tried to find it but it is never more than a few lines....)

Comment: GCE - Google Compute Engine is a cloud instance. It is not a 'large set up' It is easy and pretty straight forward and they have free credits also which will help you set it up for free and use for a while.

Comment: Ok, fair enough I'll go and try that first (not a lot of time now....). Looks like at least a better tutorial then the normal one! :P Thanks I'll accept your answer in a day or 2 unless there is an answer that explains how to do it locally with Genymotion....